# Date field in domain and g:textField tag don't work in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, bootstrap-datepicker

I have an application with an **User domain that extends from SecUser** (security user class in Spring Secrity Core). In this domain (User), I have serveral fields and one of them is: **Date birthDate**. The scaffolding create the **g:datePicker** tag but I don't like the style.

I would like to implement for example: Datepicker for Boostrap (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) but this library uses an **input type="text"** field.

In my view **(.gsp**), if I put a text input, the save and update actions don't work because in my controller when I get **userInstance.birthDate** the value is null.

If I put the **g:datePicker** tag, my controller get the value correctly.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

**EDITED**:

Code of Datepicker Bootstrap in my view:

```
<div class="input-group date date-picker" data-date-format="dd-MM-yyyy" data-date-end-date="+0d">
       <input type="text" id="birthDate" name="birthDate" value="${formatDate(format:'dd-MM-yyyy',date: userInstance?.birthDate)}" class="form-control form-shadow"/>
       <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button class="btn default" type="button">
                  <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
             </button>
       </span>
</div>
<span class="help-block">
  <h5>
       <g:message code="custom.date.picker.description" default="Select a date"/>
  </h5>
</span>
```

Now, I can get the value in my controller with **params.birthDate** but the next error appears:

```
Class java.text.ParseException
Message Unparseable date: "01-04-2016"
```

SOLVED:

The solution has been to parse correctly in Datepicker for Bootstrap library. This library uses a different parser. For example: '**01-04-2016**' in Grails is '**dd-MM-yyyy**' but in this library is: '**dd-mm-yyyy**'.

In this link the formats appear:
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#format

Besides, it is necessary to add the following lines in **Config.groovy**:

`grails.databinding.dateFormats = [
        'dd-MM-yyyy', 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S'
]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight-forward solution is to map the date field in your controller action:

```
def save( User user ) {
  ....
  user.birthDate = new SimpleDateFormat( 'dd-MM-yyyy' ).parse params.birthDate
  ...
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work because I am getting the same value in my controller: null. I can see with: log.error(userInstance.birthDate). I edited my question to add the code of the input.

Comment: @JesúsIglesias your input field is missing the `name` attribute. hence `null` in the controller. it should be `<input type="text" name="birthDate"/>`

Comment: Now. I can get the value in my controller but I get the next error: 
Class
java.text.ParseException
Message
Unparseable date: "01-04-2016"

Comment: just ran the script in groovy console: `new java.text.SimpleDateFormat( 'dd-MM-yyyy' ).parse '01-04-2016'` and got `Fri Apr 01 00:00:00 UTC 2016` back. you must have misspelled something. `MM` must be in upper case

Comment: Solved!! Thanks. It was a problem with the Datepicker for Boostrap library. In this library: '01-04-2016' is 'dd-mm-yyyy', not 'dd-MM-yyyy'.  You can check it: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#format